# Filling a database (from a temporary database) with a Many to Many relation

Tags: postgresql, insert, many-to-many

I have a temporary table that I fill in using a CSV file.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_products(
    product_marketplace_name varchar,
    product_link varchar,
    product_name varchar,
    product_description varchar,
    product_price numeric,
    product_ean numeric,
);
```

With this temporary table, I would like to complete these 3 tables :

I have created a many to many relationship:

- A product is present on several marketplaces.
- A marketplace has several products.

Marketplace Table

```
CREATE TABLE marketplace (
  marketplace_id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
  marketplace_name varchar UNIQUE
)
```

Product Table

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  product_name        text NOT NULL,
  product_description varchar,
  product_ean numeric UNIQUE,
);
```

Junction Table

```
CREATE TABLE product_marketplace (
  marketplace_id  int REFERENCES marketplace (marketplace_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  product_id int REFERENCES product (product_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  updated  date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  product_link    text NOT NULL,
  product_price   text 
);
```

I dont know how to create the relationship in the junction table... My idea is to retrieve the ids (marketplace_id, product_id) from the previous `INSERTS`

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO marketplace (product_marketplace_name) 
SELECT DISTINCT temp_products.product_marketplace_name
FROM temp_products 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO product(product_name, product_description, product_ean) 
SELECT temp_products.product_name, temp_products.product_description, temp_products.product_ean
FROM temp_products 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

....

COMMIT;
```

I tried this, but it doesnt work...

````
INSERT INTO product_marketplace (marketplace_id, product_id, product_price, product_link) 
SELECT temp_products.product_price, temp_products.product_link
FROM temp_products 
JOIN marketplace as m USING (marketplace)
JOIN product    as p USING (product)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```
````

Comment: How many columns are you inserting vs selecting?

Comment: I select 6 columns

Comment: No, you select 2 columns, price and link